# Typescript Convert Object to Array - because *ngFor does not supports iteration of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

- I don't want to use for loop to convert Object to Array like this! If doubled the process and slow down the performance of app (I'm using Ionic2 and Typescript, with Firebase)

  for(let key in data) {
      array.push(value);
  }

Is there any solution to iterate object itself(shown in picture attached) using *ngFor.

Or I can convert this Object(shown in picture attached) to Array, so that can be iterable in *ngFor.

[image]

Comment: You could create a custom pipe for it

Comment: How could I create a custom pipe for it ?

Comment: Implement the answer of Farooq into a custom pipe, then you're done

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use **Object.keys(obj)** to get named indexes. This will return an array structure which you can use/customize further. A sample use to iterate over object values may look like this

```
var persons = { 
    john: { age: 23, year:2010},
    jack: { age: 22, year:2011},
    jenny: { age: 21, year:2012}
}
```

Getting an iterator

```
var resultArray = Object.keys(persons).map(function(personNamedIndex){
    let person = persons[personNamedIndex];
    // do something with person
    return person;
});

// you have resultArray having iterated objects
```

Comment: I don't want to loop through! Is there any solution to loop through directly in dom? (Otherwise double loop will be executed!)

Comment: well, i don't have much knowledge about Ionic, but in Angular you can user  '(key, value) in persons' on iterator directives, hope it helps with your concern regarding direct manipulation of DOM avoiding a loop through.

Comment: (key, value) does not worked in Angular2 (Typescript - ES5) OR Object of Objects can't be looped through! I tried doesn't worked ;(

Comment: I created an example of how it works. Hope it helps  http://codepen.io/farooqkhan/pen/mRbMZV

Comment: Thanks Farooq. [ng-repeat="(key, value) in persons"] works well in Angular, but in Angular2 using *ngFor that [(key, value) in persons] does not worked! Where 'persons' is an Object of Objects (not Array) - as I shown in attached image of question.

Comment: @AnkitMaheshwari here's my answer to explain how to do it without looping https://stackoverflow.com/a/69219985/2482582

Answer (score 30):

Since Angular 6, there is now a keyvalue pipe operator.  Simple do the following:

```
*ngFor="let item of objectList | keyvalue"

item.key # refers to the keys (134, 135...) in your example
item.value # refers to the object for each key
```

Comment: Perfect! This should be the accepted answer. Exactly what I was needing to figure out. Thank you!

Comment: Also consider the programmatic version of this; 1) register KeyValuePipe in app.module 2) inject into constructor `private keyval: KeyValuePipe` 3) use it like this `let keyvalueData = this.keyval.transform(data);`

Answer (score 13):

If you don't need the indexes, you can use Object.values(yourObject) to get an array of the inner objects.

Answer (score 3):

The stadard library funtion `Object.entries` does that for you. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Here's an exemple of using `Object.entries` in a function to convert an object of (key -> object of type A) to a list of object of type A with the property `name` and the key as the value of that `name` property:

```
function f<A>(input: { [s: string]: A }): (A & {name: string})[] {
  return Object.entries(input)
    .map(a => {
      return {name: a[0], ...a[1]}
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the response data inside a square bracket and save it in the class.

```
this.servicename.get_or_post().subscribe(data=>
   this.objectList = [data]);
```

Comment: This won't work because it puts the entire "list" into the first entry of the array so you get like `[0:{object1: ...},{object2: ...}]`

Answer (score -6):

Adding toArray() on the pipe worked for me.

```js
// Import toArray function
import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Generic function to consume API
searchObjects(term: string): Observable<theObject[]> {
  requestUrl = this.url + term;
  return this.http.get<theObject[]>(requestUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
      // convert object to array
      toArray<theObject>()
  );
}
```