# NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays in Ionic3

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I wish to convert an Ionic's storage object to an array to be readable in a ion view.
I get this error : NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
How to convert an object to an array ?
Do i have to forEach storage the push the data to an array ?
This is the object :
[image]
Regards
Frank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript Convert Object to Array - because \*ngFor does not supports iteration of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458400/typescript-convert-object-to-array-because-ngfor-does-not-supports-iteration)

Comment: Can you show your object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6's Object.values to get an array of values:

```js
var obj = {
  "1": { prop: "xxx" },
  "2": { prop: "yyy" },
  "3": { prop: "zzz" }
}

var arr = Object.values(obj);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try an approch to get an array of the storage ionic object like this:

```
this.storage.forEach((value: string, key: string, index: number) => {
                        //console.log(key);
                        console.log('value',value);
                        });
```

It returns an array of the object but with additional values !
Strange .....
Solution from [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/data-binding-with-ngmodel-and-ngfor-results-in-empty-array/86800/4)